# Laravel: How I can return validation messages by privilege of users?

Tags: php, laravel

I have sample function for check user privilege: `is_admin(), is_university()` and `is_student()`. Returned values of functions is boolean. And I have simple validation method:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{        
    return Validator::make($data, [

        "$this->recipient" => [
            'sometimes',
            'required',
            'email',
            'exists:users,email',
            Rule::notIn([auth()->user()->email])
        ],

        "$this->subject" => 'sometimes|required|min:10',

        "$this->message" => 'sometimes|required|min:50',

    ], $this->validator_messages());
}
```

Now I can not send message by check user privilege here:

```
public function send(Request $request)
{
    $recipient = $request->recipient;

    if(User::is_student() == true AND User::is_student($recipient) == true OR User::is_student() == true AND User::is_admin($recipient) == true){
        return false; // Or here I can redirect to back.
    }

    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    $this->create($request->all());
    return redirect($this->redirectToAfterSendMessage);
}
```

In my code if sender is Student then students can't send messages to student and admins. How I can return validation message by check privileges sender and recipient? Thanks for everybody for answering!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you want to redirect back. So, instead of:

```
return false;
```

Redirect user:

```
return back()->with('error', 'Your error message');
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey Mezenin